# How to show that the set of feasible solutions of a linear program forms a convex set

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, problem-solving

How to show that the set of feasible solutions to the following linear program
forms a convex set:
Minimize $c^Tx$
subject to $Ax = b$
           and $x\geq0$

I found this problem not clear. Should I start with converting problem into canonical format? But constraints are weird.

Comment: You are missing some necessary context here. For example: What is $A$? What is $x$? What is $b$? How does $A$ act on $x$? With respect to which metric should $x$ be minimalized?

Comment: @StefanMesken A is a matrix which holds coefficients of the constraints, x is a vector of variables, b is the matrix of rhs. There is no information in the problem about them. These are what I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Ax_1=b$ and $x_1 \geq 0$ and $Ax_2 =b$ and $x_2 \geq 0$,

let $\lambda \in [0,1]$,

$$A(\lambda x_1 + (1- \lambda)x_2) = \lambda Ax_1 + (1-\lambda)Ax_2 = \lambda b + (1-\lambda )b = b$$

Also, note that since $\lambda \geq 0$ and $(1-\lambda) \geq 0$,

$$\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 \geq 0$$